# Regex to identify a Medical Beneficiary Identifier(MBI) in python

Tags: python, regex, pii

So I am trying to create a regex for MBIs (medical beneficiary identifiers) in python and my regexes wont work.

Any example of a MBi is: 1EG4-TE5-MK73

Here is the format to MBIs:

- 11-Characters
- The MBI’s 2nd, 5th, 8th, and 9th characters will always be a letter.
- Characters 1, 4, 7, 10, and 11 will always be a number.

I have tried using the following regex but to no avail:

```
mbi=re.compile(r"[1-9]{1}[^SLOIBZsloibz|^0-9]{1}[^SLOIBZsloibz]{1}[0-9]{1}-?[^SLOIBZsloibz|^0-9]{1}[^SLOIBZsloibz]{1}[0-9]{1}-?[^SLOIBZsloibz|^0-9]{1}[^SLOIBZsloibz|^0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}")
```

Any suggestions?!?!

Comment: Your pattern is using `[^SLOIBZsloibz]`, is there a reason for that? (I don't see anything about that in the format conditions) Also note that `{1}` is a meaningless quantifier, best to leave it out entirely, and you can use the case-insensitive flag to avoid having to repeat both lower and upper-case characters

Comment: What about 3rd and 6th position characters? What can they be? Any character or only any alphanumeric character? And are the hyphens optional? Will they be at fixed position only?

Comment: 3rd and 6th position can be Any character

Comment: @JamesDavinport your regex seems to be working.check here https://regex101.com/r/zX2uj8/1

Comment: Yep it is working now. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is the format to MBIs:
>
> 1. 11-Characters
> 2. The MBI’s 2nd, 5th, 8th, and 9th characters will always be a letter.
> 3. Characters 1, 4, 7, 10, and 11 will always be a number.

---

There's no mention about the **3rd** and **6th** characters, but based on your example, you can use a regex like:

```
\b\d[A-Z]{2}\d-[A-Z]{2}\d-[A-Z]{2}\d{2}\b
```

---

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yGAdQk/1)

---

Regex Explanation:
[image]

Comment: Well adding i flag will be a good thing as op said can be any letter.Otherwise a good one :)

Comment: Thank you! There are several details about the pattern that were left out by the OP. My answer is based  on the provided example - `1EG4-TE5-MK73` - which doesn't include small letters.

Comment: Well it was just a suggestion mate.

Comment: The format only allow for upper-case letters, so the solution is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so based upon your regex, there were certain things that you tried doing were syntactically not correct. Quantifying through curly braces is not needed when you want it to occur just only once due to which `{1}` becomes redundant. So I've removed this part from your regex. Second thing in your character set,

```
[^SLOIBZsloibz|^0-9]
```

as I can see you want to negate certain alphabets and 0-9 digits. You don't have to apply alternation while you are using character set `[]`. Besides negating those alphabets in your character set, if you also want to negate 0-9 number, you just have to simply put it there and your intended correct character set becomes,

```
[^SLOIBZsloibz0-9]
```

After applying these corrections in your regex, your regex becomes this, which is what you needed I guess.

```
^[1-9][^SLOIBZsloibz0-9][^SLOIBZsloibz][0-9]-?[^SLOIBZsloibz0-9][^SLOIBZsloibz][0-9]-?[^SLOIBZsloibz0-9][^SLOIBZsloibz0-9][0-9][0-9]$
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NRGsfb/1)**

Let me know if this works fine for you.

Comment: i used your code but nothing match. Are you sure that works? Scratch my code, do you know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I added in a few `\\-` so it wouldn't count the hash as a valid alpha-numeric character.

```
^[1-9][^SLOIBZsloibz0-9][^SLOIBZsloibz][0-9]-?[^SLOIBZsloibz0-9\\-][^SLOIBZsloibz\\-][0-9]-?[^SLOIBZsloibz0-9\\-][^SLOIBZsloibz0-9\\-][0-9][0-9]$
```